# How to use a custom comments template

Tags: comments

My wordpress makes use of custom post templates. I'm now trying to create a custom comments template as well.

I noticed that the comments template is called via this function
`<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>`

I checked in my functions.php and comments.php but don't see the function being declared anywhere. Can someone please advise on how to go about introducing a custom comments template?

Comment: @Chip Bennet, thanks for the heads up. Reading through that page, I notice that to set up an alternative comments template, i'd have to use this <?php comments_template( '/short-comments.php' ); ?> so am I right in assuming that I can start off by copy pasting the code from comments.php into short-comments.php and then work my way through from there?

Comment: You *can* do it that way, but why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`comments_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) template tag sets up the commenting variables and functions, and includes the `comments.php` template-part file. So, to create a custom comments template, use `comments.php`.

From there, you will need to get comfortable with the arguments, filters, and callbacks for [`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments), which is used to output the comment list, and [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form), which is used to output the comment-reply form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback function on wp_list_comments() function.

```
wp_list_comments();
```

Usually, you will find this line in comments.php file of your wordpress theme. And the output from this command is a pretty straightforward HTML structure.

Wordpress have a option of passing the callback function as an argument to wp_list_comments function.

This callback function should return the modified HTML structure of comments section, which we are looking to implement.

```
<ul class="comment-list comments">
    <?php
    wp_list_comments( array(
        'style'      => 'ul',
        'short_ping' => true,
            'callback' => 'better_comments'
    ) );
     ?>
</ul><!-- .comment-list -->
```

You can check detailed tutorial here

https://www.5balloons.info/custom-html-for-comments-section-in-wordpress-theme/