# How to replace default comments with custom HTML?

Tags: plugin-development, comments, hooks

I'm going to replace default list of comments and comment form with Facebook's comment box. As far as I know there is function [wp_list_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments). How can I replace this function with my custom one?

**Update:** I want completely ignore built-in WordPress comments.

When I try to add my code to the end of content, it works:

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'fbcommentbox', 100);
```

But the following code does not:

```
add_filter ('comments_template', 'fbcommentbox', 100);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a custom comments template](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32237/how-to-use-a-custom-comments-template)

Comment: @kraftner, my question is different. I added more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that with the following:

```
add_filter ('comments_template', 'fbcommentbox', 100);
```

we expect `fbcommentbox()` to return the **path** to the new *comments template file*. The default is the path of `comments.php`.

If you create the `fbcommentbox.php` file in your theme, then you could try:

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', 'fbcommentbox', 100);

function fbcommentbox( $theme_template )
{
    // Path to our new comment template file
    $new_theme_template = get_template_directory() . '/fbcommentbox.php';

    // Override if it exsits
    if( file_exists( $new_theme_template ) )
        $theme_template = $new_theme_template;

    return $theme_template;
}
```

If the file `fbcommentbox.php` doesn't exists then the default one is loaded instead. For a child theme we would use `get_stylesheet_directory()`.

Here's a shorter version:

```
function fbcommentbox( $theme_template )
{
    return locate_template( 'fbcommentbox.php' );
}
```

where the `locate_template()` does all the hard work.

### Update

But you mentioned you wanted to override `wp_list_comments()` instead.

Here's a way to do that by changing the `echo` argument to `false`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_comments_args', function( $args )
{
    // Display fbcommentbox.php 
    get_template_part( 'fbcommentbox' );

    // Disable output of wp_list_comments()
    $args['echo'] = 0;

    return $args;
} );
```

and output instead the `fbcommentbox.php` template.

Comment: Looks good. I work for me, but the is an another problem: it removes all the comments.php template content which could be very different in different themes. That's why I was looking for a way to override `wp_list_comments()` only.

Comment: so you want to keep the theme's `comments.php` template (for the sake of the layout) but still not use the comments in WordPress @Antonio

Comment: Yes, because `comments.php` contains border, margins, background colors, etc